# Is /storage common to all Android phones running Jellybean+?

Tags: android

I want to scan the storage to retrieve all the files whose extension matches a group of extensions.

Currently I am using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()` but that returns the path to the inbuilt storage on Samsung Galaxy Core Prime (I haven't tried on other devices) and leaves out the external SD card.

However, I have discovered that path `/storage/` is the root of both the inbuilt storage and SD card on the aforementioned device. So my question is : Is it the same in all Android devices running SDK 16+?

Please confirm that the said path exists and it's the root of both the inbuilt storage and external SD card (if any).

Comment: try below answer

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
private String[] getExternalStorageDirectoryn() {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) { //Method 1 for KitKat & above
        File[] externalDirs = getExternalFilesDirs(null);

        for (File file : externalDirs) {
            String path = file.getPath().split("/Android")[0];

            boolean addPath = false;

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                addPath = Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(file);
            }
            else{
                addPath = Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(EnvironmentCompat.getStorageState(file));
            }

            if(addPath){
                results.add(path);
            }
        }
    }

    if(results.isEmpty()) { //Method 2 for all versions

        String output = "";
        try {
            final Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command("mount | grep /dev/block/vold")
                    .redirectErrorStream(true).start();
            process.waitFor();
            final InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (is.read(buffer) != -1) {
                output = output + new String(buffer);
            }
            is.close();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(!output.trim().isEmpty()) {
            String devicePoints[] = output.split("\n");
            for(String voldPoint: devicePoints) {
                results.add(voldPoint.split(" ")[2]);
            }
        }
    }

    //Below few lines is to remove paths which may not be external memory card, like OTG (feel free to comment them out)
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            if (!results.get(i).toLowerCase().matches(".*[0-9a-f]{4}[-][0-9a-f]{4}")) {
                Log.d("Storage", results.get(i) + " might not be extSDcard");
                results.remove(i--);
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            if (!results.get(i).toLowerCase().contains("ext") && !results.get(i).toLowerCase().contains("sdcard")) {
                Log.d("Storage", results.get(i)+" might not be extSDcard");
                results.remove(i--);
            }
        }
    }

    String[] storageDirectories = new String[results.size()];
    for(int i=0; i<results.size(); ++i) storageDirectories[i] = results.get(i);

    return storageDirectories;

}
```